# Inner join the same column of a table to multiple tables

Tags: linq

I have a main table Fruit, and I'd like to join it to tables ApplePrice, PearPrice, and BananaPrice.

Fruit

```
Id    Type    Date  
--------------------  
 1    Apple   1/1
 2    Apple   1/3
 3    Banana  1/5
 4    Pear    1/7
```

Common Denominator of [Apple/Pear/Banana]Price (there are many more specific fields for each table):

```
Date    Price   F1  F2 ...
-----------------------
1/1      p1
1/2      p2
....
```

To get the price of each piece of Fruit, I join the Fruit table with each price table separately, then concatenate the results together.

If the Price tables can't be merged into one, do you have a better approach to this problem?  For example, construct one Linq query that returns all the information instead of concatenating results from multiple queries.

Appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join into` then `DefaultIfEmpty`.  The LINQ equivalent of a SQL LEFT JOIN.

```
from fruit in fruits
join ap in applePrices 
    on (fruit.Type + fruit.Date.ToShortDateString()) equals ("Apple" + ap.Date.ToShortDateString()) 
    into aps
from applePrice in aps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

This will give:

```
  Fruit | Apple Price | Banana Price | Pear Price
--------+-------------+--------------+------------
  Apple |  applePrice |         null |       null
  Apple |  applePrice |         null |       null
 Banana |        null |  bananaPrice |       null
   Pear |        null |         null |  pearPrice
```

Then select the valid fruitPrice values by the below:

```
applePrice != null
    ? applePrice.Price
    : bananaPrice != null 
        ? bananaPrice.Price 
        : pearPrice != null 
            ? pearPrice.Price 
            : 0 // Default value here if all 3 are null
```

And use LINQ to select the wanted fields.
The complete result below, I've used an anonymous class to hold my values:

```
var prices = from fruit in fruits
             join ap in applePrices 
                 on (fruit.Type + fruit.Date.ToShortDateString()) equals ("Apple" + ap.Date.ToShortDateString()) 
                 into aps
             from applePrice in aps.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join bp in bananaPrices 
                 on (fruit.Type + fruit.Date.ToShortDateString()) equals ("Banana" + bp.Date.ToShortDateString()) 
                 into bps
             from bananaPrice in bps.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join pp in pearPrices 
                 on (fruit.Type + fruit.Date.ToShortDateString()) equals ("Pear" + pp.Date.ToShortDateString()) 
                 into pps
             from pearPrice in pps.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
                 {
                     Id = fruit.Id,
                     Type = fruit.Type,
                     Date = fruit.Date,
                     Price =
                     applePrice != null
                         ? applePrice.Price
                         : bananaPrice != null 
                             ? bananaPrice.Price 
                             : pearPrice != null 
                                 ? pearPrice.Price 
                                 : 0
                 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, I am not sure if it is a better solution though since the statement that assigns a value to Price will look ugly very soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
var prices = from T in bank.students
                         join O in bank.dovres
                         on (T.code) equals

                         (O.codestu)
                         into aps
                         from applePrice in aps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join Y in bank.rotbes
                         on (T.code) equals (Y.codestu)
                         into bps
                         from bananaPrice in bps.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         select new
                         {
                             Id = T.code,
                             Type =T.name,
                             Date = T.family,
                             father=T.fathername,
                             T.adi_date, T.faal_date,
                           //  = applePrice.sal + " ماه و " + O.mah + " روز", hk = Y.sal + " ماه و " + Y.mah + " روز" 
                             hj = applePrice != null
                             ? applePrice.sal + " ماه و " + applePrice.mah + " روز"
                             :"",
                             hj1 = bananaPrice!= null
                            ? bananaPrice.sal + " ماه و " +bananaPrice.mah + " روز"
                            : "",

                         };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = prices;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "کد ";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "نام";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "نام خانوادگی";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "نام پدر";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = " عضویت عادی";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "عضویت فعال";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "کسری بسیج";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "کسری جبهه";
```

This is the best code for joining 3 or more tables.